# Hide stderr output in unit tests

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm writing a few unit tests of some code which uses sys.stderr.write to report errors in input. This is as it should be, but this clobbers the unit test output. Is there any way to tell Python to not output error messages for single commands, à la `2> /dev/null`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I suggest writing a context manager:

```
import contextlib
import sys

@contextlib.contextmanager
def nostderr():
    savestderr = sys.stderr
    class Devnull(object):
        def write(self, _): pass
        def flush(self): pass
    sys.stderr = Devnull()
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        sys.stderr = savestderr
```

Now, wrap any code snippet whose stderr you want suppressed in a `with nostderr():` and you have the localized, temporary, guaranteed-reversible stderr suppression that you want.

Comment: Wow! This is wonderful. Wasn't aware of contextlib before coz I still use Python 2.4.

Comment: @shailesh, yes, contextlib facilitates the writing of most simple context managers (writing a class with `__enter__` and `__exit__` isn't hard of course, but this way, for sufficiently simple cases, you have even less boilerplate code to write and read;-).

Comment: Why not `sys.stderr = os.devnull`

Comment: @Matt3o12: Because os.devnull is simply a string ("/dev/null" on Linux systems, for example), not a file descriptor.

Answer (score 12):

You could create a dummy file object that did nothing with its output, and set stderr to that:

```
class NullWriter:
    def write(self, s):
        pass

sys.stderr = NullWriter()
```

If you only want to quiet stderr for a specific duration, you can use a `with` statement like so:

```
class Quieter:
    def __enter__(self):
        self.old_stderr = sys.stderr
        sys.stderr = NullWriter()

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        sys.stderr = self.old_stderr

with Quieter():
    # Do stuff; stderr will be suppressed, and it will be restored
    # when this block exits
```

Requires Python 2.6 or higher, or you can use it in Python 2.5 with a `from __future__ import with_statement`.

Answer (score 5):

Another possibility (besides assigning to `sys.stderr`) is to structure your code to write errors to a file provided, but to default that file to sys.stderr.  Then you can provide a DevNull writer during testing.

If you do want to reassign sys.stderr, you can use the unittest framework to manage it for you:

```
class DevNull(object):
    def write(self, data): 
        pass

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.old_stderr = sys.stderr
        sys.stderr = DevNull()

    def tearDown(self):
        sys.stderr = self.old_stderr
```

This way, every test dev-null's stderr, but then restores it at the end of the test.

Comment: This also has the advantage that you could check the output in your test if you wanted to.

Answer (score 4):

```
class DevNull(object):
    def write(self, data): pass

sys.stderr = DevNull()
```

To have a less permanent solution, one could figure out something like as follows:

```
_stderr = None
def quiet():
    global _stderr
    if _stderr is None:
        _stderr = sys.stderr
        sys.stderr = DevNull()

def verbose():
   global _stderr
   if _stderr is not None:
       sys.stderr = _stderr
      _stderr = None
```

Function names can probably be better

Comment: I was hoping for a less permanent solution. Is there no way to wrap a command like `quiet(...)`?

Comment: No need to store a backup. Python already have one sys.__stderr__ http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.__stderr__

Comment: The reason to store the backup is so that nothing is absolute: who knows if some other larger code entity changed sys.stderr before you got invoked?  This way, you are simply undoing your first action.