# Why is my class not getting mocked in my unittest?

Tags: python, mysql, unit-testing, python-unittest

I am trying to mock GetDatabaseConnection but it is still running the code within it.

```
class GetDatabaseConnection:
    resp_dict = json.loads(get_secret())
    endpoint = resp_dict.get('host')
    username = resp_dict.get('username')
    password = resp_dict.get('password')
    database_name = resp_dict.get('dbname')
    port = resp_dict.get('port')
    connection = pymysql.connect(host=endpoint, user=username, passwd=password, db=database_name, port=port)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
```

Here is the test I have written to try to mock the class.

```
    @mock.patch("lambda_function.GetDatabaseConnection")
    def test_mock_simple_class(mock_class):
        mock_class.return_value = "test"
```

But I get the following error

```
test_lambda_function.py::TestPreSignUp::test_mock_simple_class FAILED    [100%]
test_lambda_function.py:151 (TestPreSignUp.test_mock_simple_class)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/unittest/mock.py:1334: in patched
    with self.decoration_helper(patched,
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py:117: in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/unittest/mock.py:1316: in decoration_helper
    arg = exit_stack.enter_context(patching)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py:429: in enter_context
    result = _cm_type.__enter__(cm)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/unittest/mock.py:1389: in __enter__
    self.target = self.getter()
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/unittest/mock.py:1564: in <lambda>
    getter = lambda: _importer(target)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/unittest/mock.py:1236: in _importer
    thing = __import__(import_path)
../lambda_function.py:42: in <module>
    class GetDatabaseConnection():
../lambda_function.py:43: in GetDatabaseConnection
    resp_dict = json.loads(get_secret())
```

Answer (score 1):

You are experiencing the same problem as in this other question about [importing without executing the class - python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12010140/importing-without-executing-the-class-python). Since you designed your class to have attributes that would execute the call to `pymysql`, then they would be executed right away even when the file is just imported (e.g. during mock patching) without even creating an instance of `GetDatabaseConnection`.

**src.py**

```
import pymysql


class GetDatabaseConnection:
    connection = pymysql.connect(host="127.0.0.1", user='username', passwd="password", db='database_name', port=80)
```

**test_src.py**

```
from unittest import mock

# This will read your class. And this will run your <pymsql> commands even without a running patch yet.
import src  # or <from src import GetDatabaseConnection>


# This will also read your class with or without the import above. And this will run your <pymsql> commands even without the patch yet.
@mock.patch('src.GetDatabaseConnection')
def test_try1():
    assert True
```

**Output**

```
$ pytest -q -rP

================================================================================================= ERRORS ==================================================================================================
______________________________________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting test_samp.py
E   pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)")
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
1 error in 0.22s
```

### Solution 1:

Redesign you class to not execute class-level logic by putting them inside class methods.

```
class GetDatabaseConnection:
    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = pymysql.connect(host="127.0.0.1", user='username', passwd="password", db='database_name', port=80)
```

```
from unittest import mock


@mock.patch('src.GetDatabaseConnection')
def test_try(mock_class):
    assert True
```

```
$ pytest -q -rP
================================================================================================= PASSES ==================================================================================================
1 passed in 0.03s
```

### Solution 2:

Transform your `GetDatabaseConnection` into an ordinary function:

```
def getDatabaseConnection():
    return {
        "connection": pymysql.connect(host="127.0.0.1", user='username', passwd="password", db='database_name', port=80),
    }
```

```
from unittest import mock


@mock.patch('src.getDatabaseConnection')
def test_try(mock_func):
    assert True
```

- Output same as Solution 1

### Solution 3:

Not recommendable. Don't import the file directly without a running patch. Thus, don't patch the class `GetDatabaseConnection` too to avoid reading from the file and executing `pymysql`. First, you need to patch `pymysql` before importing the file. This is very hard to maintain and would break if one of your source code files import the file containing the class `GetDatabaseConnection`.

```
from unittest import mock


@mock.patch('pymysql.connect')
def test_try(mock_pymsql):
    import src  # Or <from src import GetDatabaseConnection>
    print(f"{src.GetDatabaseConnection.connection=}")  # This will be the patched version
    assert True
```

Output:

```
$ pytest -q -rP
================================================================================================= PASSES ==================================================================================================
________________________________________________________________________________________________ test_try _________________________________________________________________________________________________
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ Captured stdout call -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
src.GetDatabaseConnection.connection=<MagicMock name='connect()' id='139647536711760'>
1 passed in 0.03s
```