# How to prevent pytest from printing local variables during a test

Tags: python, pytest

I'm executing a simple testing script with pytest. I'm testing if the creation of a database connection succeeded. 
The function that creates the database connection requires a username and a password. During the testing, pytest prints out the username and password. Obviously, I don't want passwords to be printed out to the console! How can I prevent this from happening?

I've tried multiple solutions, including using contextlib and custom created NullWriters that suppress stderr and/or stdout (for example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/1810086). However, none of it seems to have any effect.

This is the test function:

```
def test_make_db2_connection():

    # get username and password from the environmental variables
    username = os.environ['username']
    password = 'my_password' # would be: os.environ['pwd']

    # create a connection with the database
    connection = make_db2_connection(username, password)

    # assert if the connection exists
    assert connection, "Connection wasn't created."
```

See pytest's output below. As you can see, my username and (testing) password are printed. This is what I want to prevent.

```
============================================================================================================ FAILURES ============================================================================================================
____________________________________________________________________________________________________ test_make_db2_connection ____________________________________________________________________________________________________

    def test_make_db2_connection():

        # get username and password from the environmental variables
        username = os.environ['username']
        password = 'my_password' # would be: os.environ['pwd']

        # create a connection with the database
>       connection = make_db2_connection(username, password)

test_file.py:16:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

username = 'E001703', password = 'my_password'

    def make_db2_connection(username, password):
        """Creates a connection with the database"""

        dbalias = os.environ['dbalias']
>       connection = connect(dbalias, username, password)
 SQLCODE=-30082on: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30082N  Security processing failed with reason "24" ("USERNAME AND/OR PASSWORD INVALID").  SQLSTATE=08001

=================================================================================================== 1 failed in 14.19 seconds ====================================================================================================
```

Comment: You can play with the `--tb` option, e.g. `pytest --tb=no` will not print any traceback at all, `pytest --tb=native` will print the usual stack trace etc.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a solution that I can incorporate _inside_ my script. That way I can suppress output for this specific test, while still _allowing_ output for other tests. Any idea?

Comment: Ah, I see. Are you in control over `make_db2_connection`? You could add a line `__tracebackhide__ = True`, see [Writing well integrated assertion helpers](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html#writing-well-integrated-assertion-helpers). Although admitted this is more like a workaround since it requires modification of the tested code.

Comment: Solved! It is indeed a bit hacky, but hey it fits my needs. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by @hoefling! See the comments below the original question.

Solution was to use `__tracebackhide__ = True`. Downside of this solution is that you need to modify the original function that is being tested, instead of the testing script itself.